# How to make a jar file out of Google Appengine Java Project

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I'm trying to create a runnable jar file from my google appengine java webapp. My goal is to make it run without using eclipse. I tried exporting it but it doesn't work. its looking for a main class, i think.

Any help will be very much appreciated :)))

Comment: Make a very quick maven file to build into a jar.

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't help us help you. Describe exactly what you tried, and include the output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I use this plugin for maven:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.my.full.classpath.MainApp</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And the you can run with this command:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

That is enough for me.